# How to work around nvcuda.dll if using an AMD chip?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, cuda, amd-processor

I'm incredibly new to coding with python and have been attempting to install [this github project](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning). However, when running the tests, The program reads:

```
 File "C:\Users\Lindsley-Smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 70, in preload_check
    % build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.
```

How can this be fixed? I've installed everything I need for the project, even attempting to install nvcuda drivers, but this is continuing to be my singular roadblock. How can I fix/work around this?

I am on an AMD cpu.

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: GPU issues aside, the most recent update in the readme for that repo states: _If you just want to clone your voice, do check our demo on Resemble.AI - it can run for free but it will be a bit slower, and it will give much better results than this repo._ That might allow you to bypass this issue entirely.

Comment: I am using a Radeon 580x GPU. Not CUDA compatible, if I’m correct. On the resemble.ai, I want to clone someone else’s voice not my own. (Not for illegal stuff, I swear)

Answer (score 1):

`If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.`

This tells me that it can't work without using an nVidia GPU, since only those have CUDA cores, on the other hand this is because the project uses tensorflow-gpu, you could try replacing it with tensorflow (the normal one only uses the CPU's processing power), but I can't guarantee it will work (there probably is a reason it is not optional?).

I did a quick grep of the repo and turns out tensorflow-gpu is only mentioned once, and that is in the requirements file, everywhere else it is imported as tensorflow, so I'm not sure...

Comment: Thank you for looking so far into this. Would tensorflow’s pip install be CPU-only, or should I look elsewhere for the wheel?

Comment: The 'tensorflow' package is supposed to be only reliant on the CPU, only tensorflow-gpu utilizes the CUDA cores, but if your software requires the latter package, I'd expect it not to work...